# Define a local variable in Java: Integer a = 100, where is "100" stored?

Tags: java

In java, define a local variable like this: Integer a = 100. Without using new(), directly assign the value 100 to it. Then where is the value "100" stored? Stack or Heap?

Comment: The int value is a field inside an Integer object. So heap.

Comment: @WJS They didn't ask where the reference was stored. They asked where the value 100 was stored.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive Data Types. The eight primitives defined in Java are int, byte, short, long, float, double, boolean, and char – those aren't considered objects and represent raw values. They're stored directly on the stack.

But here you are not using int instead by using Integer class you are forcing java to use an object and thereby it is stored in the heap. And as mentioned in the comment a reference to this object is stored in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `a` to `100`, it automatically boxes the integer value that was first loaded onto the stack to an object reference, `Integer` type. It then stores the reference onto the stack.

You can verify this by creating a class, like so:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer foo = 100;
    }
}
```

Compile the class (`javac Test.java`) and disassemble the bytecode (`javap -c Test`).

Output:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        100
       2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: astore_1
       6: return
}
```